# NSURLDownload delegate issues

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

```
class ImageFetcher {

    /* Initialize class variables and init function */


    func fetch(){

        var imageRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: self.source)
        var imageDownload = NSURLDownload(request: imageRequest, delegate: self)

        /* does path exist */
        let directoryPath = self.destination.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
        let fileMgr = NSFileManager();
        fileMgr.createDirectoryAtPath(directoryPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: nil)

        imageDownload.setDestination(self.destination, allowOverwrite: true)
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is with the line

```
var imageDownload = NSURLDownload(request: imageRequest, delegate: self)
```

It's complaining  "Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSURLDownload' that accepts an argument list of type '(request: NSURLRequest, delegate: ImageFetcher)'
I believe it has to do with the "self".  I tried to cast it as a NSURLDownloadDelegate but it complained that it couldn't do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delcare your class as:

```
class ImageFetcher : NSObject, NSURLDownloadDelegate {
```

and then call the init line with:

```
var imageDownload = NSURLDownload(request: imageRequest, delegate: self)
```

Comment: Doing that gives me a "Type 'ImageFetcher' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'.  at the

    "class ImageFetcher : NSURLDownloadDelegate" line.

Does this mean I have to override all the required fields listed at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLDownloadDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Comment: Fix it by   "Class ImageFetcher : NSObject : NSURLDownloadDelegate {